# VB.NET Variable Passed ByRef to Constructor Available to Other Class Methods

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a class to parse templates. Here's an abbreviated version of what I have:

```
Public Class Parser
    Public Vars As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Tags As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Template As String

    Public Sub New(ByRef _Template As String, Optional ByVal _Recursing As Boolean = False)
        Recursing = _Recursing
        Template = _Template
    End Sub

    Public Sub Go()
    ' Do stuff, extract a portion of the template
    Dim Page as Parser = New Parser(portion, True)
    Page.Go()
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, it's designed to be recursive. When the class is first instantiated, the caller passes a template name to the constructor, then sets various stuff and calls `Go()`. The problem comes when it recurses: `Go()` creates a new instance, and instead of the template name, passes a portion of the template to be worked on, which is why `_Template` is `ByRef`. The problem is, the new instance of `Go()` does not have access to it. VB doesn't have pointers, so is there any way to make that reference available to the rest of the class from the constructor? I've googled around and read a number of articles here, but can't find anything that answers my question. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/object-data-type) makes it sound like the `Object` data type will do what I want, so I tried

```
    Private Template As Object
```

but it doesn't do what I want. I also found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7ee4dac-047a-48b0-ba8a-e8551414fc01/object-passed-byref-to-form-but-not-accessible-throughout-form-class?forum=vbgeneral) which seems to be asking the same question, and seems to say that changing the parm to `ByVal` does the trick, but that makes no sense.

Comment: `Go() creates a new instance` No, `new` creates a new instance.  Whats the point of it?  Your class could save portion to a variable, and `Go`  would have access to it

Comment: `ByRef` doesn’t make sense here, so remove and forget about it for now. Why does the parser parsing the “portion” need the rest of the template?

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, `Go()` creates a new instance. It's right there in the code I posted. The problem is, I want the new instance to be able to modify what's passed, which is why that parm is `ByRef`.

Comment: @Ryan The instance parsing the portion doesn't need the rest of the template, but it does need to modify the portion that was passed to it, thus the `ByRef`.

Comment: But why do you need a new instance? There wont be any different code in it than in the original.  One thing you could do is pass `portion` to `Go() as a param so it has what it needs and nothing more.

Comment: Portion should be the parameter of Go(). And Go() should be recursive.

Comment: @Plutonix I really should have waited until tomorrow to post this; it's the end of a long day and I'm tired and not thinking clearly. I trimmed the code down too much, and it's not as good a question as it could be. I need a new instance because different sets of data are passed to the class for it to work with. I've added those elements back in. But I think you and Ruard have the right idea, I should just pass the data directly to `Go()`. It just seemed cleaner to be able to pass it to the constructor.

Comment: Rather than recursion Go could remain the entry point, extract stuff and call a helper method to do the real work.  Do it in a loop if there are different parts to work on.  ctor params are nice when a class absolutely needs some bit of info; this seems not to be the case - the method needs it, not the entire class

Comment: @Plutonix I think I have a handle on it now, thanks. However, as to the underlying question: _is_ there any way to make a reference passed to the constructor available to the rest of the class?

Comment: Yes - a variable.  You dont define `Recursing` and `Template` anywhere but presumably you'd save the values passed in to them.  However thats not really what the overall asks - rather than making a var available to the instance, you *seem* to want to make it available to *other* class instances.  You could use Shared but that defeats the purpose of the child instance - it is just not needed.

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, that was another thing I cut out -- `Recursing` is a public class `Boolean` element. But the question is, is there a way to make a _reference_ passed to the constructor available to the rest of the class, not just the data, so that any changes made are reflected in the original, thus allowing the template portion to be passed to the constructor, and worked on by `Go()` I'm sorry if I'm still not clear; I'm off tomorrow, so I'll have to wait until Monday to see if I can explain it better. :)